# How could I get the letter position into alphabet?

Tags: c

I need to know the position of the letter within the alphabet.

Is there a simple way to do this without using FOR loop?

```
word[0] = hello; //H

H = position 8 into alphabet
E = position 5 into alphabet
```

Thank you

Comment: Subtract 'A' from the letter.

Comment: Assuming ascii, subtract `'A'`. There is no guarantee in the language standard that alphabetic characters are contiguous, however. That guarantee is only only present for *digit* characters (i.e. `'0'` .. `'9'`).

Comment: Gotta love [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin too much of my career spent on OS/390 to do anything but love it (hating it wasn't an option in Rochester).

Comment: What was the deal with EBCDIC?  As in why did it exist?  Other than being different. I remember having to decide to use either code page 850 and 865 with good old DOS.

Comment: @WhozCraig - does that bring back memories, I was in Rochester in 1976 & 1978 for springboard diving nationals -- but that had nothing to do with EBCDIC `:)`. Fast forward to the late 80's and there was still some computing hardware for the space shuttle motion-base simulator at JSC that read EBCDIC, a base initialization controller and another box. I'm glad that was my only brush with it `:)`

Comment: @AllanWind it's a holdover from the original punch card specification. Ironically, IBM was a *huge* fan of the ASCII standard, but didn't have time to bring their soon-to-release 360 into that fold. The irony is that 360 was *insanely* successful, and a legacy was born. I first worked on 370s in college, skipped the 380s, but foolishly mentioned IBM MF experience on a resume, and subsequently was hitched to 390s for several years (apparently a decreasingly available skillset).

Comment: @WhozCraig yeah, I remember IBM/ASCII.  Cool context.  Thanks.  I understand COBOL skills pay big bucks these days.  Maybe it's time to put that 390 back on the resume :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the letter is upper case subtract the value of 'A' and if it's lower case 'a'.  Alternatively, use `toupper` or `tolower` on the letter and use either:

```
uint8_t position(char c) {
   c = tolower(c);
   assert(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z');
   return c - 'a';
}
```

As @WhozCraig points this only works in a special case, and when you start dealing with UTF-8, a letter may not even be a single octet.

Comment: char c1 = 'h';
         char c2 = 'a';
         int position = c1 - c2;
         printf("position: %i\n", position);

Comment: `assert()`?!?  So if someone defines `NDEBUG` all error checking is abandoned?

Comment: Think of it as an executable comment.  It'll be okay, I promise :-)